# Panda transpose rows to column

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have tried doing some of the other suggestions but my dataframe is a little different. Namely, the left hand most column only has one value that's associated with several different values in other columns. Code here:

```
Year    Month   Value
        1       1
        2       6
        3       6
1980    4       6

...
        1       3
        2       4
        3       7
1990    4       1
```

The dataframe is made this way because in some code above I aggregated the data from daily to monthly, and when the new dataframe was created it only used one year for 12 months of data. Now, when I try and tranpose this, I get an error.

Here is my transpose code:

```
aam_monthly.pivot(index='Year', columns='Month', values='AAM')
```

Error: KeyError: 'Year'

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Use `aam_monthly.reset_index().pivot(index='Year', columns='Month', values='AAM')`

Comment: Nice, this works.